# Write a template that takes two column names and applies a simple equation to the values

Tags: python, python-2.7, jinja2

I have a table with a number of columns. What I am trying to do is write a jinja2 template that will take the names of two of the columns and use these to get the cell values of each column. It then needs to loop through these pairs and apply a simple mathematical formula (i.e. `cell1 * cell2`) and the only thing I need to be rendered by the template is the resultant value.

A Column has a `name` and a `cells` attribute.

This seems like it should be quite simple to achieve but I am having problems with it. It may be due to my unfamiliarity with Python as I come from a JS background and have only recently started using Python.

Any help with this problem would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

UPDATE:

`Column` A:

```
{
  name: 'Column 1', 
  cells: [
    {value: 1000}, 
    {value: 1000}, 
    {value: 1000}
  ]
}
```

`Column` B:

```
{
  name: 'Column 5', 
  cells: [
    {value: 11}, 
    {value: 39}, 
    {value: 50}
  ]
}
```

This template is applied to values in a table which is a React component, and is evaluated on the back-end.

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: what is the input into the template? a list of `Column` instances? Some sample code would be very useful.

Comment: @Crispin The input is going to be the column names.

Comment: so we are talking about html tables and columns?

Comment: I posted an update. The table is made using React

Comment: I am still confused how the template has access to the table. when you render the template do you pass the table to it? I.e. `template.render(table=the_table)`. Or, do you just pass the column names, I.e. `template.render(col1=name1, col2=name2)`

Comment: Ideally it would just be a column names

Comment: if all that's passed to the template are the column names, how does the template know anything about the contents of the table?

Comment: Yeah I don't know. That's the part I can't figure out, it needs to find the cell values of the columns using the name.

Comment: does python have access to the table, or is it generated elsewhere?

Comment: python does yes, it knows about the table. It looks like this: `{name: "Table", columns: [...]}`

Comment: it sounds like you need to pass the table to whatever calls your template (are you using Flask?) or do the arithmetic server-side

Comment: so the columns are python dictionaries?

Comment: yes they are dictionaries

Answer (score 0):

If this is done in python this is what you need:

```
a = {
  'name': 'Column 1',
  'cells': [
    {'value': 1}, 
    {'value': 2}, 
    {'value': 3}
  ]
}

print a['cells'][0]['value']*a['cells'][1]['value']
```

Comment: I updated the question as there are two columns that need to be looped through and then have the equation applied. Also you need to find the correct column as only the `Column` name will be passed into the template

Answer (score 0):

Based on our conversation, it doesn't sound like the heavy lifting should be done within the template, but instead in Python itself. Let's say we have a dictionary for each column (`a`, `b`, `c`, ...) and we want to multiply all the cell values of "Column 1" with "Column 2":

```
a = {
  'name': 'Column 1',
  'cells': [
    {'value': 1},
    {'value': 2},
    {'value': 3}
  ]
}

b = {
  'name': 'Column 2',
  'cells': [
    {'value': 4},
    {'value': 5},
    {'value': 6}
  ]
}

# assemble the dictionaries into a list
dicts = [a,b] 

# create a new dictionary mapping column names --> cell values
data = {x['name']:x['cells'] for x in dicts} # {'Column 1': [{'value': 1}, {'value': 2}, {'value': 3}], 'Column 2': [{'value': 4}, {'value': 5}, {'value': 6}]}

col1 = 'Column 1'
col2 = 'Column 2'

col3 = []
# zip the columns of interest
for el in zip(data[col1],data[col2]):
    # extract the cell values for each zipped pair
    values = [x['value'] for x in el]
    # do the multiplication
    c = values[0]
    for x in values[1:]:
        c *= x
    col3.append(c)
```

You could then pass `col3` directly to the template:

```
template.render(data=col3) # col3 = [4, 10, 18]
```

EDIT

If `cells` were a list of dictionaries having unique keys, one could do something like this:

```
a = {
  'name': 'Column 1',
  'cells': [
    {'value1': 1},
    {'value2': 2},
    {'value3': 3}
  ]
}

b = {
  'name': 'Column 2',
  'cells': [
    {'value1': 4},
    {'value2': 5},
    {'value3': 6}
  ]
}

dicts = [a,b]
data = {x['name']: {k:v for d in x['cells'] for k,v in d.items()} for x in dicts}
# {'Column 1': {'value3': 3, 'value1': 1, 'value2': 2}, 'Column 2': {'value3': 6, 'value1': 4, 'value2': 5}}

a = data['Column1']
b = data['Column2']

col3 = {'Column 3':dict([(k, a[k]*b[k]) for k in b.keys() & a.keys()])}
# {'Column 3': {'value1': 4, 'value2': 10, 'value3': 18}}
```